# wcf datamemberattribute casing

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF Service I have a property declared as such:

```
public string PropertyName
{
    get { return propertyName; }
    set { propertyName = value; }
}
```

In my Client, when I add a service reference to the service, the imported `.cs` file has the same property, except it has lost its casing, as such:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
public string propertyName
{
    get
    {
        return this.propertyNameField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.propertyNameField = value;
    }
}
```

(Notice the lowercase `p` on `propertyName`.)

Is there anything I can do so that consumers actually get the property with the intended Casing, ie: `PropertyName`, not `propertyName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly setting the Name in the DataMember?  For example:

```
[DataMember(Name="PropertyName")]
public string PropertyName { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Comment: Hello Scott.  I just gave your method a try, sorry but it didn't work.  
Thanks for the help though. 
Steven

Comment: Hello Scott. 
My apologies. Your suggestion did work. 
The problem was that I didn't have the:
    [DataContract(Name = "Account", Namespace = "http://companyname/webservices/schema/account")] 

attribute arround the class. when I added it everything worked as expected. 

Thanks,
Have a good one. 
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the DataContract attribute in place correctly? Also make sure that you're applying the DataMember to the property and not the private string.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataObject {

    string propertyName;

    [DataMember]
    public string PropertyName {
        get { return propertyName; }
        set { propertyName = value; }
    }
}
```

The full code of the class would be helpful.